# Excel VBA 2010 - Mimic user slicer interaction

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

From checking various sites, the only known(?) way to select one item from a slicer is to deselect all other others by iterating through the array of items. When a user clicks an unfiltered slicer, it instantly deslects all other items - is there a way to mimic this behavior with VBA (deselect all except for the item clicked)? Specifically, the number of items to filter is too long and takes takes too long to iterate through, even with calculations off.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_A").ClearManualFilter

With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_A")
    For i = 1 To .SlicerItems.Count
        If .SlicerItems(i).Caption = Target.Value Then
        Else
        .SlicerItems(i).Selected = False
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Edit: To clarify why I am wanting to do this with VBA, I am making a "drill in" macro, where I can click on a cell (that is the result of a formula, not a pivot table cell), and it will take me to the appropriate tab and adjust the slicers as necessary to show where that number comes from.

Comment: My advice is to not worry about the odd downvote. However, if it does bother you, please add a comment, rather than adding voting commentary to your post - it does not belong there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to work with the pivot table directly:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("FIELD").CurrentPage = Target.Value
```